# Opening Workbook as object from Ms-Word and Find text using checkbox, Delete entire Row then Close workbook

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, ms-word, userform

My situation is I am opening `Workbook` from `MS Word` where I find some Text and delete entire Row of found Text. To achieve that I am using [Userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bmiz.png) having Check-boxes and Buttons. The code below loop through all check-boxes and if `C.Value` return `True` it perform action by pressing **CEEMEA** Button.

I am having problem with `Excel Object` naming `Xc`.

For the first time I run **CEEMEA** macro it run properly (Opens workbook--> Find text--> delete row--> close workbook, etc);

but second time, it return error *`Run-time Error '13': Type mismatch`.* , so far I think there may be something left on first run, which I did not Quit/Close/set to nothing, (duplication of workbook)

I had checked all spellings, Everything is Correct.

I had `Xc.Quit` at the end, and `Set Xc= Nothing`.

I did not understand where its going wrong. I thing on the first run there may be something which I did not `Quit` or `Set` to `Nothing`. I put whole code below. kindly help...

If there is beter way of doing this job kindly suggest.

```
Dim Xc As Object
Set Xc = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Xc.Visible = True
Set Wb = Xc.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\dell\Desktop\EMEA CEEMEA\EMEA CC FINAL LIST.xls")

Dim C As MSForms.Control
For Each C In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(C) = "CheckBox" Then
    If C.Value = True Then
    If C.Caption = "Select All" Then
    Else

    Dim ff As String
    ff = Trim(C.Caption)
  With Wb
        .Application.Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        .Application.Range("A1").Select

        .Application.Cells.Find(What:=ff, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        .Application.ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
        .Application.Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Application.Range("A1").Select

  End With

    End If
    End If
    End If
Next C

Wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
Workbooks.Close
Set Wb = Nothing
Xc.Quit
Set Xc = Nothing
```

Comment: You didnt specify Worksheet. Try `.Worksheet("SheetName").Find ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to open workbook and make it visible. This may work for you. `Workbooks.close` will close all workbooks if exist.

```
Dim WB As Workbook
Set WB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\dell\Desktop\EMEA CEEMEA\EMEA CC FINAL LIST.xls")
Dim C As MSForms.Control
For Each C In Me.Controls
If TypeName(C) = "CheckBox" Then
If C.Value = True Then
If C.Caption = "Select All" Then
Else


With WB
    .Application.Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    .Application.Range("A1").Select

    .Application.Cells.Find(What:=C.Caption, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

    .Application.ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
    .Application.Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

End With

End If
End If
End If
Next C

WB.Close SaveChanges:=True
Workbooks.Close
Set WB = Nothing
```